# Smoothest way to migrate vSphere/vCenter?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

So I have an older Dell VRTX running on ESXi 6.0 hosts, with vSphere and vCenter in place. No vMotion, however. The hardware is past its prime so I am purchasing a new Dell MX740c to ultimately take its place. The new replacement will be running ESXI 6.7 U3. The vSphere and vCenter licensing should carry over between the old and new environment.

I am thinking about spinning up a new, different vSphere/vCenter environment on the new Dell. What would be the most straightforward way to migrate the VM's? I assume I'd just power off each VM on the old Dell and use the VMware Standalone Converter to move them over to the new Dell.

Would the actual VCSA VM require any config changes after the move when it's on the new Dell? The VCSA is just another VM running on one the VRTX hosts on the old Dell. This is my first time working through this scenario and I'm just starting to read online VMware docs to get my ducks in a row!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backup with Veeam and restore @ your new location.

Comment: I do have Veeam B&R running as a VM on the old Dell. And I have an admin client app running on my own physical workstation. Would I need to install anything in the new vSphere/vCenter environment?

Comment: Thinking out loud, I suppose I can open a ticket up with Veeam going through the scenario. Good tip for sure, since that migration route would be likely more efficient than my own workstation acting as the middleman.

Comment: So I would have a new VCSA VM installed on the new Dell server, and then go through the VBR VM running on my old Dell server to restore all VM's onto the new Dell. Other than the VBR VM and the VCSA VM. When I'm done the only thing I would use the VMware Standalone Converter for would be for shutting down the VBR VM on the old Dell server and migrating it over to the new Dell, correct?

Comment: What is your VCSA version running on old hardware? In case it is 6.0, you should upgrade it to 6.7 so it can manage 6.7 hosts. As for the procedure, you are right, move all VMs with VBR, afterwards you can use either VMware Standalone Converter or StarWind V2V Converter. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind before doing any update (ESXi or/and vCenter) that your vCenter version should match the ESXi version you'll update.

Have a look here to check if your hardware fit the esxi version you'll install :
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php

Have a look here if you can upgrade from 6.0 to 6.7 directly :
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/sim/interop_matrix.php#upgrade

Check here the compatibility matrix between vCenter and ESXi (the version you're looking for) :
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/sim/interop_matrix.php#upgrade